Терминал не реагирует на команды в пайчарме
Все нормально работало, но в какой-то момент терманил перестал реагировать на команду "manage.py test.." и ничего не отображает, даже ошибок, просто переходит к новой строке для ввода. Что делать? (Я новичок)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
